# Opencart Checkout Issue

Tags: opencart, checkout, confirmation

I have created a website in OC. But at the time of checkout there are 6 steps to follow. I followed all 5 steps but when i go to 6th step it shows me error as below:

> Notice: Error: Could not load model checkout/extension! in D:\hosting\5308266\html\mastore\watches-ecommerce\system\engine\loader.php on line 48

What is wrong with my website?

Comment: What is version of your OpenCart Installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no model named `extension` , i think you installed some extension related to checkout that replaced your original file. i think there would be this line

```
$this->load->model('checkout/extension');
```

in `catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php` removing this line might solve your problem.

If that does not work re-upload all the files of `catalog/controller/checkout` folder. (ASCII mode is fine, no need to upload with binary mode )

Answer (score 0):

Try and Reupload following folder in Binary Mode:

```
catalog/controller/checkout/
```